# Сортировка выборки из базы данных

Tags: c++

Есть выборка из базы данных в виде .txt, из нее надо сделать сортировку автоматически, строк 70к+.

Подскажите как лучше реализовать, заранее спасибо.

**Обновление**

Есть выборка из бд

```
| шифр | фио | код1 | код2 |
```

В коде `1` есть значения `0`, нужно отделить в разные файлы будь то `txt` или в `excel` те, что со значением 0, в другой отсортировать по код2, код 2 несколько вариантов до 10.

**Обновление 2**

Язык C++, так как так решило руководство, чем мотивировано не знаю, честно. В день по 3-5 выборок до 200к строк. Может на других языках есть лучшее решение данной задачи?

Comment: загрузить обратно в базу, отсортировать и выгрузить

Comment: Использовать утилиту командной строки: `sort <input.txt >sorted.txt`. А если серьёзно вы бы хоть привели кусочек файла и ожидаемый результат. А лучше — что вы пытались сделать на данный момент и почему не получилось.

Comment: Насколько часто повторяется данная задача? Насколько требуется автоматизировать данный процесс? Почему именно C++ как базовый ЯП?

Comment: Не очень понятен текст вопроса. Уточните, Вас интересует именно сортировка в смысле изменения порядка строк в файле или "разбрасывание" строк одного файла в несколько других по упомянутым Вами критериям?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выше хорошее скриптовое решение, которое требует использование *NIX или cygwin как базовой платформы.

Аналогично, для платформ на базе Windows можно реализовать аналогичные скрипты на PowerShell или с использованием скриптовых языков (perl/php/python/ruby и т.п.). Такой выбор рекомендую наличием развитых средств работы с регулярными выражениями, программа в результате будет в 1-4 строки, в отличие от C++-кода, который растянется на полтора экрана.

Если интересно, могу накидать пример на PowerShell.

---

Как и обещал, примерный вариант скрипта на PowerShell, получилось в одну срочку:

```
cat $args[0] | % -Process { add-content ("code"+$_.Split('|')[3].Trim()+".txt") $_ }
```

Данный скрипт разбирает файл, который пришёл в качестве входного параметра, и раскидывает его содержимое (в зависимости от 3-го столбца) по файлам code<код>.txt. В качестве примера использовался вот такой входной файл (не обессудьте, генерировать 70к строк было лень):

```
| шифр | фио | код1 | код2 | 
| 1234 | ВАС | 0    | 2345 |
| 2345 | АВС | 0    | 3231 |
| 1237 | ВСА | 1    | 2567 |
| 2532 | АСВ | 0    | 1254 |
| 8654 | САВ | 1    | 9532 |
| 7759 | СВА | 0    | 1245 |
```

Выполняется командой

```
PowerShell.exe ./script.ps1 test.txt
```

На выходе в данном случае получается 3 файла code0.txt, code1.txt, codeкод1.txt :-). Обработка (теоретически) поточная, т.е. по одной строке, в память всё грузить не будет. Если требуется сортировка, то, конечно, этот вариант не пройдёт.

По умолчанию выполнение скриптов из командной строки заблокировано политиками, требуется запустить PowerShell.exe с правами администратора и выполнить команду

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned
```

Вернуть всё как было после тестирования можно, выполнив команду

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy restricted
```

Как альтернатива, можно всё записать в одну строку — как в *NIX:

```
PowerShell "cat ./test.txt | % -Process { add-content (\"code\"+$_.Split('|')[3].Trim()+\".txt\") $_ }"
```

В этом случае никаких дополнительных политик включать не потребуется.

Надеюсь, это поможет.

Использованные материалы:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192072/how-to-process-a-file-in-powershell-line-by-line-as-a-stream
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592531/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-powershell-script
- man

Comment: да интересно, если можно посоветуйте еще и соответствующую литературу

Comment: @Link, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714469(v=vs.85).aspx, здесь живёт руководство. Пример накидаю позже немного. Если кратко — в PowerShell можно использовать .Net-классы (в том числе регулярки и прочие методы вида String.Split(new []{'|'});, что позволяет написать однострочники не сильно хуже линуксовых (хотя синтаксис и хромает в части лаконичности).

Comment: Для полноты картины: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm awk для Windows :-) если сортировки не нужно, можно только им и обойтись, практитчески без изменения решения выше. Если нужна, то можно тоже средсвами awk сделать, но там нюансов побольше. Или поискть sort для Windows, к примеру: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm и тащить полностью Cygwin или msys не нужно.

Comment: @MonahTuk ну понятно, что можно, но PS есть сейчас на всех серверных win-платформах «из коробки», ничего делать не надо :-)

Comment: Ладно, нужно просто подождать экспериментов автора и результаты по скорости.

Answer (score 2):

Если данные помещаются в память: любой доступный вариант сортировки. В случае C++: загрузить в `std::vector` и натравить `std::sort()` со своим компаратором.

Если данные не помещаются в память:

- https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0 и
- https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0

**Обновление**

Если хватает производительности, то можно попытаться выполнить задачу при помощи Shell скрипта. Простой пример с `sort` предложил  Tagir Valeev в коментариях к вопросу. Под уточнённые требования эта команда, несколько усложняется:

```
sort -t '|' -n -k 5 < input.txt | awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {out1="output_1.txt"; out2="output_2.txt"} { if ($4 == 0) { print >> out1;} else {print >> out2;} }'
```

Shell-магия выше делает: указывает разделитель полей для `sort` в `|`, сортирует по пятому полю (`код2`), после чего отправляет данные на вход `awk`, который по полю 4 (`код1`) разделяет поток на два файла: где `код1` - `0` и где `код1` - не ноль. Если сортировка не нужна, то убирается `sort` и `input.txt` подаётся прямиком на awk:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {out1="output_1.txt"; out2="output_2.txt"} { if ($4 == 0) { print >> out1;} else {print >> out2;} }' < input.txt
```

что существенно увеличит скорость обработки.